# Datagridview controls

Tags: c#

I have a form with two gridview  one displays the results from a search .textbox and the other displays a selected row from the first grid view . Then the rows in the second gridview is saved into a database call unpaid checks.

```
   private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i <= 0; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
           
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["selectrow"].Value = true))
            {
                Formq pan = new Formq();
                pan.ShowDialog(); 
                string may = Formq.mark1;
               productBindingSource4.AddNew();
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1].Cells["quantity"].Value = may;
               int qu = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["quantity"].Value.ToString());
                string pp = dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                Double rpp = Double.Parse(pp);
                Decimal rrpp = (decimal)rpp;

                Decimal tp = rrpp * qu;
                dataGridView2.Rows[dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["tprice"].Value = tp + ".00";

                Double sum = 0;
                for (int f = 0; f < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; f++)
                {
                    sum += double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[f].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                }
                string msun = (sum.ToString());
                libt2.Text = msun;
```

Then it’s form is closed and a dynamic button is created. When I want to update the data in the unpaidchecks . I use this

```
  private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        salesitems op = new salesitems();
        op.Show();
        int i = 0;
       Button btn = sender as Button;
       string btntext = btn.Text;
       kk.getunpaid(int.Parse(btn.Text));
       op.dataGridView2.DataSource = kk.getunpaid(int.Parse(btn.Text));
        
        foreach (var  dy in kk.getunpaid(int.Parse(btn.Text)))
        {
            op.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["quantity"].Value = dy.quantity.ToString();
            op.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Tprice"].Value = dy.tprice.ToString();
            i++;
            op.libtabsno.Text = dy.tabel_sno_.ToString();
            op.libuser.Text = dy.user.ToString();
            op.libtno.Text = dy.tabel_no_.ToString();
            op.libt2.Text = dy.total.ToString()
```

But the problem is , it doesn’t add a new row.
This code dose not work when the

productBindingSource4.AddNew();
The dynamic button is clicked
I need help

Comment: What is this `for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i <= 0; i++)`? Set a breakpoint at the first line in this block to see if the execution pauses. If you want to loop backward then replace that line with: `for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.

Comment: That part is working but yo add a new row to the datagri2dview2 when I want to update an existing tabel is the problem